# How make a single CSS class to make two text lines, like Title and Subtitle?

Tags: html, css

My code currently looks like this:

```css
.data-title {
  font-weight: bold;
}

.data-content {
  color: gray;
}
```

```html
<p class="data-title">
  Title
</p>
<p class="data-content">
  Content
</p>
```

The result is how I intended it to look:

[image]

However, I would like to make the following two changes:

1. Decrease the margin between the elements.
2. Have a single class on a parent element instead of the two classes on the paragraphs that automatically identifies the first line and second line and applies the current styles.

```
<div class="my-class">
  <p>Title</p>
  <p>Content</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `:first-child` selector to select the first element, and then combine this with the `+ *` selecter to get the element following it. To decrease the margin, simply set `margin: 0` (or whatever value you see fit) to all paragraph elements in your `div` (or you could add them to only the ones you already selected, depending on whether there are any other paragraphs that should retain their margin).

```css
.my-class span {
  display: block;
}

.my-class :first-child {
  font-weight: bold;
}

.my-class :first-child + * {
  color: gray;
}
```

```html
<div class="my-class">
  <span>
    Title
  </span>
  <span>
    Content
  </span>
</div>
```

Comment: Instead `<p>` I try use `<span>` but it not jump line. There are a way to jump line using CSS?

Comment: I don't quite understand why you are trying to do all this, to be honest. Semantically it might make more sense for each element to have its respective class, and if you want to have line breaks, why not use block elements in the first place? But you can indeed use `<span>` inline elements and set them to `display: block` to achieve the same result. I updated my snippet to reflect hat.

Answer (score 1):

If i am right then you are asking for this may be:-

**1st method:-**
You can use span tag

```css
p {
  color: blue;
  font-size: 40px;
  margin-bottom: 10px
}

p span {
  color: red;
  display: block;
  font-size: 15px;
}
```

```html
<p>Title<span>Content</span></p>
```

**2nd Method :-**

```css
div.main p {
  color: blue;
  font-size: 40px;
  margin-bottom: 0px
}

div.main p+p {
  color: red;
  font-size: 20px;
  margin-top: 0px
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <p>Title</p>
  <p>Content</p>
</div>
```

**3rd Method:-**

```css
div.main p {
  color: blue;
  font-size: 40px;
  margin-bottom: 0px
}

div.main p:nth-child(2) {
  color: red;
  font-size: 20px;
  margin-top: 0px
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <p>Title</p>
  <p>Content</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the p-element in the title block loses its margin.
After that: style all elements by their own html class.

```
<div class="title_block">
  <p>Title</p>
  <span>Subtitle</span>
</div>

<style>
  .title_block p {
    margin: 0;
    font-size: 28px;
    font-weight: bold;
  }

  .title_block span {
    font-size: 20px;
  }

</style>
```